# How to draw a sprite on a moving canvas

Tags: c#, canvas, xna, sprite

I generally figure this sort of thing out normally but I am stumped. I suspect theres a mathematical combination I have missed but anyway.

I have a moving background (currently goes up and down from top to bottom)
I have a moving object (currently moves left and right from the centre of the canvas programatically).

So this is the question, How can I make an object move relatively to the position on the canvas in x and y directions?

Here is my relevant codes:

```
//Helper method
    private Vector2 CalculateDirection()
    {
        Vector2 calculatedDirection = new Vector2((float)Math.Cos(direction),
            (float)Math.Sin(direction));
        calculatedDirection.Normalize();
        return calculatedDirection;
    }
```

object on canvas

```
    public void Update(GameTime gameTime, Vector2 center)
    {
        this.currentCentre = originalCentre - center;
        //movement logic here
        Vector2 calculatedDirection = CalculateDirection();
        //deltaTime = ((float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds) / 15f;

        if (speed > 0f || speed < 0f)
        {
            ///TODO: work this out!!
            Velocity = calculatedDirection * speed;
            float dir = (originalCentre.Y - currentCentre.Y);
            position.X += Velocity.X * (1.0f - 0.9f);
            position.Y = dir;// *(1.0f - 0.9f); 
        }
    }
```

canvas moving methods

```
    private void determinePitchSize()
    {
        int newHeight = Convert.ToInt32(pitch.Height * ratio);
        this.canvas = new Rectangle(
            0, posHeight,
            device.PresentationParameters.BackBufferWidth,
            newHeight
            );
    }

    public void increasePosHeight()
    {
        posHeight++;
    }

    public void decreasePosHeight()
    {
        posHeight--;
    }

    private void determineDirection()
    {
        if (!direction)
        {
            if (this.canvas.Height + this.canvas.Y <= this.screenY)
                direction = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (this.canvas.Y >= 0)
                direction = false;
        }
    }
    private void useDirection()
    {
        this.determineDirection();

        if (direction)
            this.increasePosHeight();
        else decreasePosHeight();
    }
```

If you need any more info I can add it here.

Thanks

Comment: Just add the canvas position to the object position before drawing?

Comment: I think I have overcomplicated it, I will try to strip it down a little and see if I can get it to draw properly. I suspect when I figure out that bit, I'll resolve it. Ok so drawing it in the middle of the canvas is easy. I have that mastered as position = center in the update method.

Comment: As I mentioned, keep a relative position and do `position = center + relativePosition`. The simple case you mentioned relates to a relative position of `(0, 0)`.

Comment: Thanks, I have answered this question thanks to your help.

Comment: I have removed tag(s) from your question's title based on  _[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)_ where the consensus is **no** _they should not_.

Comment: Sorry, just used to trying to make it faster for someone to see it and think, hey, i know some of that stuff. I dont usually look at tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so thanks to Nico, I was able to answer this.

```
    Vector2 Velocity { get; set; }
    Vector2 relative { get; set; }
    public void Update(GameTime gameTime, Vector2 center)
    {

        this.currentCentre = center;

        Vector2 calculatedDirection = CalculateDirection();


        if (speed > 0f || speed < 0f)
        {
            Velocity = calculatedDirection * speed * 0.1f;
            relative = relative - Velocity;
            position = currentCentre + relative;

        }
    }
```

The velocity creates object movement to test that it ends up in a different place.

Relative starts at 0,0 (the center) and is adjusted by the velocity.

Position is then set to the centre plus the relative position. which has been set by the velocity.